# Import swift framework in swift project issue

Tags: swift

I checked all answers to similar problem and none helped.

I created a simple swift framework for testing. When I drag it to a Objective-C project, I can then import the header and use my simple class within Objective-C classes, np. Now when I do the same with a swift project, I can't reference my class (gives unidentified etc ...), I can import the header without error, just xcode can't see the class. That class is public and has one simple public method.
What does xcode need to be able to see that class in swift project when the process is so easy in OBJ-C project?

Comment: Have you added files in build Phases for all targets?

Comment: it's all set when I drag it in the swift project just like it is when I drag it to the objc project, it's all the same really so I guess there's an extra step for swift to work with swift .....